# How to list all values of 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, class, service, 2d

I want to be able to pass an entire row of a 2d array to a service method I created in Java. (I'll use a as the values I want to pass). The service method accepts a 2d array as an argument and sets a variable to that array. So basically I have an array with values for someArray[0][0]

```
 0 1 2 3 4
```

0| x  x  x  x x
1| a  a  a  a  a
2| x  x  x  x  x
3| x  x  x  x x

Can I simply pass someArray[1]
Leaving out the second set of square brackets to assume I want the whole row?
OR is is possible to say someArray[1][0-4]

Comment: Why don't you try both of those, and see what happens?

Comment: You may want to read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html); scroll down about halfway and it talks about multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When invoking a method the arguments passed must match the parameters defined in the method.  So if your method accepts a multidimensional array, passing a single array is not possible.  You would need to pass the entire multidimensional array to the method and iterate through the outer and inner array.  One solution to work around this is to overload the method to accept a single array and wrap the array in another array:

```
public class PassArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] arrays = {{"x","x","x","x","x"},{"x","x","x","x","x"},{"x","x","x","x","x"},{"x","x","x","x","x"}};
        iterate(arrays[1]);

        for(String[] array:arrays){
            for(String s:array){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void iterate(String[][] arrays){
        for(String[] array: arrays){
            for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
                array[x] = "y";
            }
        }
    }

    public static void iterate(String[] array){
        String[][] arr = {array};
        iterate(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I read the OP as already having a method which takes a 1d parameter.

Comment: @Code-Guru I read it differently, `The service method accepts a 2d array as an argument `